# A discount of 15% is offered

Tags: word-order, ellipsis

Are the following sentences natural?

1. > A discount of 15% is offered on an order for 10–29 copies, 20% on 30–59, and 25% on 60 or more.
2. > A 15% discount is offered on orders for 10–29 copies, 20% on 30–59, and 25% on 60 or more.
3. > A 15% discount is offered on orders of 10–29 copies, 20% on orders of 30–59, and 25% on orders of 60 or more.

Answer (score 2):

The customer places **an order for** *n* copies, and the vendor's discount policy is stated most clearly as applying to **orders of** *n* or more copies.

But your variants are not really ungrammatical, merely susceptible to a copy-editor's pencil.

Comment: A webpage of the University of Michigan has "30% off on an order for 10 or more copies." lsa.umich.edu/herbarium/publications.html

Comment: As I said, it's not really ungrammatical, merely something a meticulous copy editor would catch.

Comment: The prepositions are deictic here in your order placement/order fulfillment scenario; it's possible for  speakers to put themselves in the listener's shoes, so to speak.

Comment: Is "A 15% discount is available for orders of 10–29 copies, 20% for 30–59, and 25% for 60 or more" correct?

Answer (score 2):

All of these are fine.  I prefer "orders of", and I also prefer the active voice, but that's a question of *style* not *grammar*.

> **We offer** a 15% discount on **orders of** 10–29 copies, 20% on 30–59, and 25% on 60 or more.